# Get parameters passed by url in ionic 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have passed parameters in URL to my ionic application

```
http://localhost:8100/welcompage/overview?brand=bmw
```

I am using ActivatedRoute to retreive the data passed as parameters in the URL

```
   constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
             console.log(params['brand']);
        });
    }
```

the output is always "undefined" meanwhile there are parameters in the URL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First method:

```
  let brand = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('brand');
```

Second method:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(

  (data) => {

    console.log(data.brand)

  }

);
```

method1 or method2 fit your needs when You already define brand params on your route   url/:brand.
but if You use query params url?brand=value1&property2=vaule2...
You could get query params data using method3:

method3:

```
this.route.queryParams
  .subscribe(params => {
    console.log(params); // { brand: "bmw" }
    let brand = params.brand;
    console.log(brand); // bmw
  }
);
```

Comment: still undefined

Comment: answer edited .. You could use second method after importing import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

Comment: I thing your problem will be solved when You apply  method3 ^^

Comment: yes it works but what's the deffirence between params and queryParams ?

Comment: router params should be defined in your angular router

Comment: welcompage/overview/:brand

Comment: but for query params You only need  and separated  with '?' for the first params for next params You only need to add '&'

Comment: example : http://localhost:8100/welcompage/overview?brand=bmw&property2=value2&property3=value3&property4=value4 ....

Comment: then will be  transformed as an object when you get query params data

Comment: {brand:bmw,property1:value1,property2:value2,property3:value3,property4:value4}